# From JSON file to CSV file

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a snippet of my json file below. Is there any way to use Python and transform this to a nice CSV file? So things like text and sentiment would have its own columns?

```
{
   "status":"OK",
   "totalTransactions":"1",
   "language":"english",
   "url":"http://well.com",
   "results":[
      {
         "text":"food",
         "sentiment":{
            "score":"0.456369",
            "type":"positive"
         }
      }
   ]
}{
   "status":"OK",
   "totalTransactions":"1",
   "language":"english",
   "warningMessage":"truncated-oversized-text-content",
   "url":"http://www.times.com",
   "results":[
      {
         "text":"food",
         "sentiment":{
            "score":"0.678684",
            "type":"positive"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

If not I would like to pull specific info from it. I've tried this code but keep getting the following error. I suspect it has something to do with the brackets/formatting of the json? How can I fix this best?

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
pprint(data)

ValueError: Extra data: line 15 column 2 - line 30 column 2 (char 367 - 780)
```

Comment: You're asking at least two questions (and hardly made any attempt to solve either). Which are how to fix the invalid json data and how to turn it into a nice csv file. Best to cut it down to one or the other. Also, please elaborate on what should go in the "sentiment" column since it's comprised of two sub-items. It also looks like "results" is a list and therefore could contain more than one result—which might contain different sub-items. Is that possible and how should it be handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer to the first part of your question that addresses the improperly formatted JSON file problem. It attempts to convert what's in the file into list of objects (dictionaries) and names the result `data`:

```
import json
import tempfile

# Fix the invalid json data and load it.
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as temp_file:
    temp_file.write('[\n')
    with open('json_to_csv.json', 'rb') as data_file:
        for line in data_file:
            temp_file.write(line.replace('}{', '},{'))
    temp_file.write(']\n')
    temp_file.seek(0)  # rewind
    data = json.load(temp_file)

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))  # show result
```

Comment: Thanks I think it was the brackets that threw me off the most resulting in errors everywhere but after clearing it up with this code my other question was solved!

Comment: You're welcome. A valid JSON document consists entirely a single [JSON-type value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example). However since this value can be of type `Array` or `Object`, both of which can contain other values.

Answer (score 2):

The JSON is indeed not valid, notice in line 15: `}{`

You are ending the first / outer object and beginning a new one, basically concatenating 2 distinct JSON strings.

To fix this you could create an array out of them by surrounding them with square brackets and add a comma between the two objects:

```
[{
   "status":"OK",
   "totalTransactions":"1",
   "language":"english",
   "url":"http://well.com",
   "results":[
      {
         "text":"food",
         "sentiment":{
            "score":"0.456369",
            "type":"positive"
         }
      }
   ]
},{
   "status":"OK",
   "totalTransactions":"1",
   "language":"english",
   "warningMessage":"truncated-oversized-text-content",
   "url":"http://www.times.com",
   "results":[
      {
         "text":"food",
         "sentiment":{
            "score":"0.678684",
            "type":"positive"
         }
      }
   ]
}]
```

You can then iterate through this array:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
    for entry in data:
        print "%s;%s" % (entry['url'], entry['status'])
```

Answer (score 0):

With corrected CSV as chrki pointed out, the full python source would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
    out = open('out.csv', 'w+')
    out.write("url;totalTransactions;language;status;text;score;type\n")
    for entry in data:
        out.write("%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s\n" % (
            entry['url'],
            entry['totalTransactions'],
            entry['language'],
            entry['status'],
            entry['results'][0]['text'],
            entry['results'][0]['sentiment']['score'],
            entry['results'][0]['sentiment']['type'])
)
```

Comment: Can I know more about how the [0] works in entry['results'][0]['text']? I received a KeyError on results there thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with loading the json into a python dictionary.
Consider using the python csv module to write the csv output file.

```
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html
```

The keys will become the header row and then for each item, you can create a row and input them into it.